# Limit row a table in SQL and Insert new rows on Top

Tags: sql, insert, limit, rows

I have a **SQL Server database** table : History_KH
It look like:

[image: History_KH Table]

Now I want to limit row number of this table (ex : 200 rows)
And when I insert new rows from code, It will insert on top of table. That's mean : Insert new rows on top of database table and the old rows over of 200 counts will be delete.
Please support me.

Comment: Rows in the table have no order when stored. When SELECT you can decide read-order (ORDER BY clause).

Comment: You generally can't control _where_ your RDBMS will insert the rows.  As to limiting to 200 records, that is a different question.

Comment: Please update your question with the database you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm using SQL sever.   Because my db will update by minute ( 1 minute = 1 row updated) so db will bulge out very fast. If have way to limit row ex : 200 rows will reduce the size for databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really limit a table for a fix number of records but you can get rid of unwanted records. Assuming you are on SQL-Server

```
--STEP1 :Do your insert here

--STEP2: Delete older records over 200 ordering by dateTime column
;WITH CTE AS (

  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime DESC) rn 
  FROM YourTable
)
DELETE CTE WHERE rn > 200
```

Comment: It seems to be a suitable solution. I'll try. Thank you so much for support me.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't even post what database you are using.  I'm assuming mysql.

Assuming you want to order by Datetime and Username is unique, use this update...

```
update `History_KH` set `Username` = $myUser, `Datetime` = $myDatetime,
`Datechange` = $myDatechange, `Value` = $myValue where `Username` in 
(select `Username` from `History_KH` order by `Datetime` limit 200)
```

Comment: Do we know that he is using PHP, or even MySQL?

Comment: Nope, but my best judgement tells me theres a very good chance he is.

Comment: I upvoted your comment BTW on him pposting the DB he's using.  I meant to post that myself, but got caught up writing this update statement. hehe

Comment: Agreed.  This is a common problem on SO with newbies posting questions and not labelling the database.  BTW be prepared to find out he is using Postgres or some other weird flavor.

Comment: I know right?   Would figure if he was.   haha.  I know pgSQL too tho,  I learned that before mySQL so no worries.   I'm a LAPPer